# How can I insert some variable into allure decorators?

Tags: python, automation, pytest, python-decorators, allure

I need to pass some variable into allure decorator, because I want to add some test data to my reports, how can I do that?

```
import allure


@allure.title("Do that")
@allure.step("Make sure that some_param == {I NEED TO PASS expected HERE}")
def test_1(data_for_test):
   expected, real = data_for_test
   assert expected == real
```

Also how can I insert values into alure decorators, using this?

```
def some_func():
    some_var = "qwe"
    with allure.step("Some text with some {some_var}"):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `allure.dynamic` to access `allure` functions

```
def test_1(data_for_test):
    expected, real = data_for_test
    allure.dynamic.description(f'Make sure that some_param == {expected}')
    assert expected == real
```

Use `f-string` to insert the data to `allure.step` as well

```
def some_func():
    some_var = "qwe"
    with allure.step(f"Some text with some {some_var}"):
        pass
```